# Can mock objects setup to return two desired results?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Can mock objects be used to return more than one desired result like below?

```
mockObject.Setup(o => o.foo(It.IsAny<List<string>>())).Returns(fooBall);
mockObject.Setup(o => o.foo(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(fooSquare);
```

Comment: With what mocking framework?

Comment: the build time is far greater than the time someone takes to answer this here. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use these setups. Thus arguments of `foo` method call are different (any integer and any list of strings), you have two different setups here, each with its own return value. If you would have same arguments, then last setup would replace previous setup(s).

Remember - each setup is defined by member you call and arguments you pass.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, because the two `foo` methods take different parameter types, they are overloads, and as Sergey states, these are regarded as entirely separate methods to both the compiler, and to `Moq`.

In the specific case where you want to return different results for the *same* method, depending on the values of the inputs, you can use `It.Is<>` with a predicate matcher to specify the filter to be applied to the parameters. Define these from most generic to most specific, e.g. focusing on just the `o.foo(int)` overload:

```
mockObject.Setup(o => o.foo(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(defaultFoo);
mockObject.Setup(o => o.foo(It.Is<int>(i => i == 5))).Returns(fooBall);
mockObject.Setup(o => o.foo(It.Is<int>(i => i > 50 && i % 2 == 0)))
   .Returns(fooSquare);
```